# Trying to pass a gpg encrypted file to a password field in a python script while in WLST

Tags: bash, encryption, python-2.6, wlst

I have basically 4 files, a shell script, a python script, a properties file and a gpg encrypted password file.The shell script which initiates the WLST environment and calls a python script. The properties file has a username variable and username and a password variable with no password in it. The encrypted password file has the password. How would I go about decrypting the password file and passing it into the properties file's password variable all while in WLST?

On I have tried to run it on RHEL 2.6.32

```
import subprocess 

Password = subprocess.check_call(["gpg", "--quiet", "--decrypt", "passwordfile.gpg"])
```

But all that comes of it is an error saying

> no module named subprocess

Comment: Is your python version older than 2.4?

Comment: I have python 2.6

Comment: WLST runs with older version of python. For instance in WebLogic 12.2.1.3 , WLST runs Python version 2.2.1, module subprocess does not exist in this version.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin, You were right. My box version is 2.6 but my WLST version is 2.2. Thank you!